# What kind of PCI slot is this and what video card can I use?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci

I tried an AGP card, but it was a little too small. So what PCI slot is this?

[image]

Can I get a graphics card that fits there that does not need a power supply?

Would one of these work?

- http://newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814139062R
- http://newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814129042

I need to output to a monitor and projector.

Comment: Which of the three slots in the picture are you asking about.

Comment: It was the orange one. Some reason I thought it was an AGP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orange slot is PCIE 16x, the small one is PCIE 1x and the larger white one is PCI. You can get a cheap video card that will fit the PCIE 16x. Most of the cheaper PCIE 16x cards will run you about $50 and have DVI, VGA, and HDMI ports. You would use the VGA port to connect to your projector.

By the way, a lot of cards you have posted there are AGP (old school connection) and PCI which would fit your larger white slot. However, since PCI is a bit older, you'll often find that they have a similar price to the newer and cheaper PCIE 16x cards. Not only are they slower and older, some newer computers might not have a PCI slot and therefore you wouldn't be able to salvage your new card into a new computer.

You can tell that the orange slot is *not* AGP for the simple fact that you have the tiny PCIE 1x slot there. They never made a PCIE 1x slot on the same motherboard that they did the AGP slots. There is a 5-10 year difference in the technologies.

Comment: Actually, there *are* a few mobos with both AGP and PCIe. But only a few.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably toss http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131339 in there. I feel stupid right now ;/

Comment: > They never made a PCIE 1x slot on the same motherboard that they did the AGP slots - How I work **now** on non-existent MB?!